# PHP - Precise removal of a modular string

Tags: php, string

I have got a question reagrding php strings.

There is this string, and in it I have got one section with bb codes.
like this:

```
 Mixed all type of things

and edited it

cool stuffasdasdasd

[img]http://google.com/image.jpg[/img]
- [url=http://google.com/]Google one[/url]
- [url=http://google.com/]Google two[/url]
- [url=http://google.com/]Google three[/url]

some more cool stuff
```

Now I want to remove the block with the [img] tag until the last one of the list with the urls.

If this is the end of a file, I have done that with strpos and removed the last bit, but now conent could be in this string after that field, and the list can be 1 link, or 500 link, or there also could not be a list at all. If there is not list at all, I could handle that case with strpos again to check, but what shall I use to remove only the list and its title image and nothing more or less? Also I can not only look for the last bb code tags since, after that section other bb codes could be used, so it has to strictly just use the last bit of the list. If there is anything dividing a similar entry at the bottom for example and the list, it was not part of the list and shall not be the end position of the part of the string beeing removed...

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you very much

Regards Arkensor

Comment: It's not clear what do you want exactly. To remove all `[img] + list` blocks, or to remove all paragraphs beginning with `[img]`, or ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your string is called `$myOldString`, then:

```
    $myNewString = preg_replace($myRegexPattern,"",$myOldString);
```

Where `$myRegexPattern` is the pattern you wish to remove from your old string.

`$myNewString` will then be the new string without the bb code in it.

Example code:

```
$myOldString = "Mixed all type of things

and edited it

cool stuffasdasdasd

[img]http://google.com/image.jpg[/img]
- [url=http://google.com/]Google one[/url]
- [url=http://google.com/]Google two[/url]
- [url=http://google.com/]Google three[/url]

some more cool stuff";

$myRegexPattern = "/[img]http://google.com/image.jpg[/img]/";
$myNewString = preg_replace($myRegexPattern,"",$myOldString);

echo $myNewString;
```

Result of echo:

```
Mixed all type of things

    and edited it

    cool stuffasdasdasd


    - [url=http://google.com/]Google one[/url]
    - [url=http://google.com/]Google two[/url]
    - [url=http://google.com/]Google three[/url]

    some more cool stuff
```

**[img]http://google.com/image.jpg[/img] is gone**

Let me know if that worked for you!

*More on preg_replace: [PHP DOCUMENTATION](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)*

Comment: This already look great, but I need those - url bb codes, which are part of the list to disappear too. This is the key problem, as I need to find out where the block of urls ends so that only the url and the head line image for them disappear, and not a random url that might be also anywhere in the string - Also there could be anythign inside those title [img] tag and any links to any website and any title withithn the url bb tags

Comment: @Arkensor Please explain again what you need to disappear. For example, if you have `lsfkj sdflkj [url=http://google.com/]Google one[/url] asdfklj`, what do you want to NOT disappear?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/MFHVHrD.png what is inside the img tag, at the top is modular but it only has 2 cases, to take that as fixed. now in the string after that image as title, there is a list of links in bb tag format, and all those links including the headline should be removed and a line break before and after the block, so after the php part is done it looks like that block never existed in this string. Oh and thank you for your quick reply's +1

Comment: @Arkensor Your welcome! :) If this question worked for you please also accept it (with a green checkmark) so that future users know that it worked for you.

Comment: I will, but still it is not the final result I need ... that is what i am struggeling with. Read my comment before your post, I described what is missing for my problem!

Comment: @Arkensor If I understood correctly, you want to take out the `- [url=http://google.com/]Google one[/url]` and the line breaks before and after. First try `$myRegexPattern = /\\n- [url=http://google.com/]Google two[/url]/` and let me know if that cleaned out some of the things that needed cleaning.

Comment: This gives nothing out for me. The pattern seems to not work at all! Yes I want to remove the title and all the entries for the list with that - [URL] stuff and the linebreaks before the block. It should be like this: Before: http://i.imgur.com/f2wNbbR.png -- and after: http://i.imgur.com/VIt9KRq.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109888/discussion-between-webeng-and-arkensor).